# $C\lVert\sum_i a_{ii}\rVert \ge \lVert(a_{ij})\rVert$ for matrices with entries in a $C^*$-algebra

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra and $(a_{ij}) \in M_n(A)$ be a positive matrix. Does there exist a constant $C \ge 0$ (not depending on the $a_{ij}$) such that
$$\lVert(a_{ij})\rVert \le C \Bigl\lVert\sum_i a_{ii}\Bigr\rVert?$$

**Attempt**: Choose a faithful representation $A \subseteq B(H)$. Then $M_n(A) \subseteq M_n(B(H)) = B(H^{n})$ so we have
$$\lVert(a_{ij})\rVert = \sup_{(x_1, \dotsc, x_n) \in (H^n)_1} \sum_j \Bigl\lVert\sum_i a_{ji} x_i\Bigr\rVert.$$

How to proceed?

Comment: If you don't care if $C$ depends on $n$, then yes. If you do care, then not.

Comment: @DiegoMartínez $C$ can depend on $n$. What did you have in mind?

Comment: The map $M_n(A) \to A$ given by $(a_{i,j}) \mapsto \sum a_{i,i}$ is completely positive with norm $n$.

Comment: @JamieGabe This does not help. From your hint, we get $\|\sum_i a_{ii}\| \le n\|(a_{i,j})\|$ and we need the inequality in the other direction.

Comment: Ah, I misread the the problem! Whoops! For the implication you want, you can use that $(a_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^n \leq 2^{n-1} \mathrm{diag}(a_1,\dots, a_n)$. The $2^{n-1}$ is definitely not optimal, but it works. To show the inequality, use the $n=2$ case over and over again (which is quite easy to prove) by considering matrices which "look like" $2\times 2$-matrices embedded in $n\times n$-matrices with a $n^2-4$ entries being zero.

Comment: @JamieGabe Thanks for your comment. Please check out my answer. We can replace the  factor $2^{n-1}$ by $n$.

Comment: Ah, yes, this exercise in Paulsen's book is the correct generalisation of the n=2 case I mentioned above (the estimate I got applied the n=2 case over and over again to get a (quite bad) upper bound). This is much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer arose by a discussion with @JamieGabe in the comments.

One can prove that
the map
$$\Phi: M_n(A) \to M_n(A): A \mapsto n \operatorname{Diag}(A)-A$$
is completely positive [Paulsen, "Completely bounded maps and operator spaces", exercise 3.6].

In particular, it is positive. Hence, writing $A= (a_{i,j})$ as in the OP, we obtain
$$A \le n \operatorname{Diag}(A)$$
and taking norms leads to
$$\|A\| \le n \lVert\operatorname{Diag}(A)\rVert=n \max_{i=1}^n \|a_{i,i}\| \le n \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,i}\right\|.$$

Comment: As you [indicated](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407455/c-sum-i-a-ii-ge-a-ij-for-matrices-with-entries-in-a-c-algeb#comment1044867_407455), you are using @JamieGabe's [hint](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407455/c-sum-i-a-ii-ge-a-ij-for-matrices-with-entries-in-a-c-algeb#comment1044862_407455), and it would be appropriate explicitly to acknowledge that. \\ Also, TeX note: $\lVert\operatorname{Tr}\rVert$ `\lVert\operatorname{Tr}\rVert` spaces better than $\|\operatorname{Tr}\|$ `\|\operatorname{Tr}\|`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the suggestions. I edited the post to give credit and I will keep your Latex suggestion in mind.